# How to search textbox value in Excel sheet and return data to other textboxes

Tags: excel, vb.net

I'm new to VB.Net and I have learnt how to get data from Excel to a `DataGridView`. Now can anyone help me learn how to get Excel data into textboxes?

I have a form with 6 textboxes and a search button. When I enter a value in `textbox1` and click on the search button, I want to search an Excel file which is selected by an `OpenFileDialog` and saved in the `destination1` string

```
destination1 = destipath & Filename.Text & "_" & dtedate.ToShortDateString & ".xlsx" '& Format(TimeOfDay, "h.mm.ss tt")
```

The Excel sheet1 has ID,  Name,Father, Mother, Address and Phone. The VB.Net form has 6 textboxes. When I enter, for example, ID as 30 in textbox1, the code must search for ID 30 in column A. If found then textboxes 2-6 must display Name, Father, Mother, Address, Phone.

The sheet rows are dynamic but the columns are fixed. I have written code to do this in Excel VBA but I am trouble writing code to do it in VB.Net?

I have tried this in VB.Net but does not identify the `LookIn` and `LookAt` like in Excel.

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
    Dim xlappFile As Excel.Application = Nothing
    Dim xlFile_WB As Excel.Workbook = Nothing
    Dim xlFile_WS As Excel.Worksheet = Nothing
    Dim xlFirstfile_WS1 As Excel.Worksheet = Nothing
    Dim FoundRange As Excel.Range
    Dim searchID As String
    searchID = Textbox1.Text

    xlFile_WB = xlappFile.Workbooks(destination1) ' destination1 is selected by 'user
    MessageBox.Show(destination1)
    xlFile_WS = xlappFile.Worksheets(1)
    FoundRange = xlFile_WS.Cells.Find(What:=searchID, LookIn:=Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlFormulas, LookAt:=Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole)

    If FoundRange Is Nothing Then
        textbox2.Text = "not found"
        textbox3.Text = "not found"
        textbox4.Text = "not found"
        textbox5.Text = "not found"
        textbox6.Text = "not found"
    Else
        textbox2.Text = FoundRange.Offset(0, 2).Value
        textbox3.Text = FoundRange.Offset(0, 3).Value
        textbox4.Text = FoundRange.Offset(0, 4).Value
        textbox5.Text = FoundRange.Offset(0, 5).Value
        textbox6.Text = FoundRange.Offset(0, 6).Value
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: and the result was?

Comment: The result in excel was it fetches the values in col b,c,d,e,f and displays in textbox2, textbox3, textbox4, textbox 5, textbox 6. If textbox 1 is not found all tetxboxs will show not found. 

This code was written in excel but I want to learn how to implement this in vb.net

Comment: I have replaced the excel code to implement in VB.Net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike under Excel/VBA, In VB.net you will need to scope the Excel constants by their namespace, like this:

```
FoundRange = xlFile_WS.Cells.Find(What:=searchID, LookIn:=Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlFormulas, LookAt:=Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole)
```

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. Now I have a new issue at  line
 xlFile_WB = xlappFile.Workbooks(destination1)

An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in WindowsApplication11.exe

Comment: xlAppFile is still null at this statement. You need to assign it `=New Excel.Application`, use `xlAppFile.Workbooks.open`,  etc. Pretty much like in VBA, with a slightly differetn syntax (i.e. without the `Set` keyword).

Comment: Thanks I have got it now

Comment: Dear A.S.H 

How to serach only in Col B and only till the lastrow instead of the wholeXL  to improve the speed?